# How do I draw a custom 3d surface using three.js?

Tags: math, 3d, three.js

What functions/math do I use to draw a 3d surface? For example, how do I generate z = sin(x+y)? How are the points calculated and drawn? I couldn't find any examples.

Comment: z=sin(x+y) is the implicit equation f(x,y,z)=0 with f(x,y,z)=z-sin(x+y). To plot an implicit equation, you need a *marching cubes algorithm*. See [this article](https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/marchingcubesjs.html) on my blog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/PlaneGeometry

Something like this contains vertices. If a vertex consists of [x,y,z] you can apply your function there by looping through all the vertices.

http://aerotwist.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-shaders-part-1/

this tutorial is an example how you can use shaders to do the same thing MUCH faster

I believe that this tutorial is a great starting point for all things realtime 3d:
http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/

Comment: I don't understand. How do I generate a surface from a set of points?

Comment: I'd say it's not trivial. I'm not sure what advice to give though. Perhaps looking at how the plane geometry gets constructed might help. I'd take a look at an obj file as well, could give some insight into the anatomy of a mesh. 

Why don't you start by creating a simple plane, have it render on screen, and then look at it's properties, and try to change the vertices.

Comment: Another way to go if you want straight-up math and no modeling whatsoever is too look at shadertoy, or glsl.heroku, but i would assume that if you don't understand the concept above, raymarching may be a bit over your head :)

Answer (score 10):

Following examples are linked from three.js website:

- http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Graphulus-Function.html
- http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Graphulus-Surface.html

both of these examples are using [THREE.ParametricGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/geometries/ParametricGeometry)

Comment: i voted for this because it seems to be exactly what the author wants, but this ParametricGeometry seems no different than the plane?

Comment: well it does not create normals until your function inits every vertex, probably saving time and memory.

Comment: There may be faster ways to do this, but the graphulus function is what I believe the user is asking for in the question. Although it may take a while to go sort out the [code](https://github.com/stemkoski/stemkoski.github.com/blob/master/Three.js/Graphulus-Function.html) if you are not familiar with threejs, but the method is fairly straight forward.